# Mvn project plugins not found.

Tags: maven

Bought the Spring Data book and try to "mvn install" the sample code on STS and have the following:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

// This is the Maven output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spring Data Book
[INFO] Spring Data Book - JPA
[INFO] Spring Data Book - MongoDB
[INFO] Spring Data Book - Querydsl
[INFO] Spring Data Book - Neo4J
[INFO] Spring Data Book - JDBC
[INFO] Spring Data Book - Redis
[INFO] Spring Data Book - GemFire
[INFO] Spring Data Book - REST exporter
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO]      
[INFO] Building Spring Data Book 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    
[INFO] Installing C:\spring-data-book\pom.xml to C:\Users\A27L4PT\.m2\repository\com\oreilly\springdata\spring-data-book\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-data-book-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO]  
[INFO] Building Spring Data Book - JPA 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO 
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.1.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO]  
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spring Data Book .................................. SUCCESS [3.292s]
[INFO] Spring Data Book - JPA ............................ FAILURE [0.074s]
[INFO] Spring Data Book - MongoDB ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spring Data Book - Querydsl ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spring Data Book - Neo4J .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spring Data Book - JDBC ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spring Data Book - Redis .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spring Data Book - GemFire ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spring Data Book - REST exporter .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.592s 
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 17 11:34:55 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.1.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.1.6: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.1.6 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add surefire to your depencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

This version might be wrong. Did not find 2.1.6 on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: No! plugins are not dependencies!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a typo in one of the source files. Search all pom.xml files for "2.16" and after verifying that you are dealing with the surefire plugin version, change that to "2.1.6", which is [the latest valid version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) as of today.

If you can't find any reference to this version in the pom files, then add a plugin management section to the root pom.xml:

```
 <build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.6</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
 </build>
```